# Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int

Tags: php, pdo

My code:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', 'root', 'password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
...
$count = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable');
```

I'm trying to count all records in `myTable` and store that number as `$count`. How can I make this happen?

I get this message: `Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int`. To my understanding, it is not an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, that query will return a PDO statement. Then you can use that statement to get the item of interest.

```
$statement = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable');
$result = $statement->fetch();
$count = $result[0];
```

This gets the statement from your query, then gets the first row (the only row from this query) and then stores the count, $result[0], into a variable named $count.

Answer (score 1):

the thing is `query` function returns you a reference to a statement. From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

```
Return Values

PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.
```

In order to get a particular field use something like that

```
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM myTable LIMIT 1');
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = $row['total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The method of Object [PDO::fetachAll()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php), return an array;

and the function [count()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php), accepts mixed parameters and returns integer value.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', 'root', 'password');

$query = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable')->fetchAll();

$countQuery = count($query);
```

Comment: Although the code may speak for itself providing some details would help improve the quality of your answer!

Comment: Sorry, you are all right, I was working and answered too fast. thanks @mrun